# "Missing character: There is no ` in font nullfont!" using contour gnuplot

Tags: pgfplots, fonts, gnuplot

The following MWE produces the warning

> Missing character: There is no ` in font nullfont!

when compiled with pdflatex or lualatex.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot3[contour gnuplot] {x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your example can't be tested without gnuplot. Can you provide the file directly?

Comment: I can not reproduce the error - it compiles fine for me. Fully updated macTeX and gnuplot 5.4 patchlevel 2. Edit: sorry -it is just a warning - I get the same one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I compile the example with TeX Live 2020 (downgrading to `compat=1.17` that's not really relevant), I see in the log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.3.22)  23 JAN 2022 15:25
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
[...]
runsystem(gnuplot "schmidgnu_contourtmp0.script")...executed.

PGFPlots: reading {schmidgnu_contourtmp0.table}
Missing character: There is no ` in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ` in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ` in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ` in font nullfont!
[...]
```

The only difference with TeX Live 2021 is that the warning also appears on the console, because now the LaTeX kernel sets `\tracinglostchars=2` (which was previously equivalent to setting it to 1) so the warnings also appear on the console.

The warnings are completely harmless.

You can remove those spurious warnings, which are due to how Ti*k*Z sometimes parses its code, by adding

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\tracinglostchars=0\relax}
```

in your document preamble after you're sure that everything is typeset properly.

Comment: while the warning is normally harmless it can also indicate a coding error somewhere in tikz. Can you sent me the table file so that I can try without gnuplot?

Comment: I opened an issue here https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/424

Comment: If I compile with lualatex, the error is
`Missing character: There is no {`} `(U+0060) in font nullfont!`
`Missing character: There is no ` (U+0060) in font nullfont!`
`Missing character: There is no ` (U+0060) in font nullfont!`
`Missing character: There is no ` (U+0060) in font nullfont!`