# baposter: "Missing character: There is no E in font nullfont!"

Tags: pdftex, baposter

Recently, whenever I use the baposter class there is a large amount of errors of the following type:

```
Missing character: There is no E in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no y in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no C in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
```

How can I fix those? It seems to have something to do with the "eye catcher", because the missing characters when reading from top to bottom in order are "EyeCat...".

### Minimal Working Example

```tex
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{}{Eye Catcher}{Properties of Elementary Random and Preferential Dynamic Networks}{}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Using baposter.cls from http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/baposter/baposter.cls.

### Versions

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.3
texlive 2021.61403-1
```

Comment: Don't give minimal examples as external links. Copy them into your question.

Comment: probably you _always_ had those warnings but they just went to the log, latex recently changed the default value of `\tracinglostchars` so this warning now appears on the terminal as well.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/631173/4427

Comment: @egreg the warnings appearing now is the same issue but the actual warning in each case indicates an error in the document or in tikz or a package (the one you reference lead to a fix in tikz to remove a stray backtick) so there may be a new issue here that is worth checking, if an example is posted here.

Comment: I can no reproduce the issue:. `pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3)`. Only warning: `Snakes have been superseded by
decorations. Please use the decoration libraries instead of the snakes
library` from `tikzlibrarysnakes.code.tex`.

Comment: @SimonDispa: You are using MiKTeX whereas I am using TeX Live, maybe that is the reason. I get the snakes warning too but I can remove the snake dependency as I don't use it's functionality, this is not related to this issue.

Comment: @KonradHöffner that doesn't matter. I won't download and unpack an unknown file if it is not strickly necessary. So if you want help, add the code of a small but complete example to your question.

Comment: The example errors for me `! Package geometry Error: \paperwidth (0.0pt) too short.`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Unfortunately, StackExchange doesn't allow me to put baposter.cls because the file is too large, even if I remove all comments. However I added the .tex file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Sorry, the MWE was wrong, I added the necessary content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class does basically something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
hello

\begin{tikzpicture}
\setbox0=\hbox{abc}
\node{\usebox0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is simply wrong. As the warnings tells you the box is stored with nullfont active, so it has no content. One really wonder why no user never complained that this content is lost.

Make a bug report. Or use something else to create a poster (I would suggest for example the poster library of the tcolorbox package).

Comment: Unfortunately the bug tracker at https://code.google.com/archive/p/baposter/issues seems to be archived. I will try to get in touch with the author.

Comment: Unfortunately his baposter address does not work, I guess the class is not supported anymore.

Comment: I have an updated version where this, and several other bugs have been corrected. Also the documentation is greatly improved. See https://github.com/pietvo/baposter

Comment: @PietervanOostrum I think you should either discuss with ctan if you can take over the maintenance or give your version another name and upload that to ctan.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, yes I have been thinking about that. I think that under GPL I could just do that without changing the name. Changing the name just for an update is generally frowned upon, and I agree that this is usually a bad idea. But I also think it might be better to try to contact the original authors if only as an act of courtesy. I'll let the idea simmer for a couple of weeks first.

Comment: @PietervanOostrum: I am having the problem again and returned to this post from Google :-) Did you get a reply from the original authors? Is there an official solution now?

Comment: @KonradHöffner No, I haven't been able to contact the original authors. I have tried email and some socila media, but no luck. Did you have this problem with my version (https://github.com/pietvo/baposter) or with the one in TeXlive?

Comment: @PietervanOostrum: I had this problem with TeXlive but I now switched to your version which fixed it, thanks!