# Wrapfigure problem in Baposter

Tags: wrapfigure, posters, baposter

I am using baposter and IAHR conference poster templet. But when I include a second wrap figure it is not placed at al and going in the next page.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% LaTeX Template for IAHR YPN Congress

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue}

\usepackage{amsmath} % For typesetting math
\usepackage{amssymb} % Adds new symbols to be used in math mode
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables
\usepackage{enumitem} % Used to reduce itemize/enumerate spacing
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for multiple columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em} % Slightly increase the space between columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % No horizontal rule between columns

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for flow chart
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz libraries required for the flow chart in the template

\newcommand{\compresslist}{ % Define a command to reduce spacing within itemize/enumerate environments, this is used right after \begin{itemize} or \begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Defines the color used for content box headers

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}
{
headerborder=closed,
colspacing=1em,
bgColorOne=white,
bgColorTwo=white,
borderColor=lightblue, 
headerColorOne=black, 
headerColorTwo=lightblue,
headerFontColor=white, 
boxColorOne=white, 
textborder=roundedleft, 
eyecatcher=true,
headerheight=0.1\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=roundedright, 
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, 
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
{\includegraphics[height=6em]{YPN_logo.jpg}} % First university/lab logo on the left
{\bf\textsc{NLO calculation}\vspace{0.5em}} % Poster title
{\textsc{Tanmoy}} % Author names and institution
{\includegraphics[height=6em]{Institution_logo.png}} % Second university/lab logo on the right

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Abstract}{name=abstract,column=0,row=0}{
\vspace{0.6em}


\vspace{0.3em} % When there are two boxes, some whitespace may need to be added if the one on the right has more content
}


\headerbox{Materials \& Methods}{name=method,column=0,below=abstract,bottomaligned=conclusion}{ % This block's bottom aligns with the bottom of the conclusion block
First, we calculate the partonic cross section up to the NLO order. We only use pQCD for \textit{asymptotically free} quarks and gluons.
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{1.3in}
\centering
\scalebox{0.5}[0.4]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a) {\(i\)};
    \vertex [below right=of a] (b);
    \vertex [below right=of b] (c);
    \vertex[right=of c](d1);
    \vertex[right=of d1](e1);
    \vertex[below left=of c](d);
    \vertex[below left=of d](e){\(j\)};

    \diagram* {
      (a) -- [fermion,edge label=\(q(p)\)] (c),
      (c) --[scalar,edge label=\(\phi(q)\)] (e1),
      (c) --[fermion,edge label=\(\Bar{q}(p')\)] (e),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{wrapfigure}
Then the partonic cross section
\small{
 \begin{equation}
     \sigma_{ab}=\frac{1}{4p.p'}\int d\Pi N\Sum\mathcal{M}_{ab}\mathcal{M}_{ab}^\dagger
 \end{equation}
}
 For the LO contribution to the partonic cross section
 \small{
 \begin{equation}
     \Delta^0_{q\Bar{q}}=\Delta^0\delta(1-\tau) \qquad \text{where} \; 
    \Delta^0=\frac{\pi}{2N}\hat{Y}^2_\epsilon
 \end{equation}
}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.9in}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{f1_cal.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
}
\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: baposter is not in texlive and personally I wouldn't use it, it is quite buggy (there seem to be a variant which correct some of the bugs see the comments there, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632507/baposter-missing-character-there-is-no-e-in-font-nullfont/632537#comment1585080_632537). Also wrapfig is a very fragile environment and I wouldn't use that in a poster anyway.

Comment: size commands do not take an argument. `\small{...}`  makes the whole document small, not the part in `{...}`

Comment: Try adding some text after the second wrapfigure and `\end{poster}`.  Also, `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]` will always fit in the alloted space.